# Best way to write any id in every log entry in my .net standard library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard-2.1

My fully developed library has multiple logging entries for debug , error and info etc.
Now I want to append any id say <12asdf> in all of my log entries for specific methods:

Library:

```
public class YourLibrary{
    public void Test(){
        log.entry();
         .
         .
        log.debug();
         .
         .
        log.exit();
    }
}
```

Application:

```
var mylib = new YourLibrary();
mylib.Test();
```

So now whenever any log is entered it should append the id in all the logs for my specific methods.
Suggest a possible way so as to not change any of the log entries in the library.
Any idea if this can be achieved using callback.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the log class (specifically i want to know if all of that is static).

Comment: What logging framework is in use? What "ID"s are you talking about?

Comment: When a library method makes a logging call, you can modify the log message before it is actually logged by calling a callback function. The specific implementation steps of this method are related to the logging framework you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute) to automatically get the name of the calling method and use it as id.

In your logging class:

```
public void Entry([CallerMemberName]string caller = default)
{
    // TODO: write to the log.
}
```

At the call sites you don't have to supply this parameter which is optional (because of `= default`). The C# compiler will supply it for you.